# In Python, how do I change which class's attribute a function will look for based on a parameter?

Tags: python, python-class, class-attributes, first-class-functions

I'd like to use the same function twice but change which class attribute the function will use. It would look similiar to below:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.primary_color = 'blue'
        self.secondary_color = 'pink'

    def show_color(self, color_attribute)
        print(color_attribute)

player = Player

print(player.show_color(primary_color))
>>>'blue'
print(player.show_color(secondary_color))
>>>'pink'
```

This particular color example may not be very helpful but the project I'm working on would greatly benefit from this ability.

Comment: What exactly can be the argument for `show_color`? An arbitrary string, a one of specially prepared constants, something else?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the function `show_color` should rather be static, since it does not use the class attributes directly. A fast solution would be to pass the attributes directly to the function:

```py
player = Player()
print(player.show_color(player.primary_color))
>>>'blue'
print(player.show_color(player.secondary_color))
>>>'pink'
```

But as I said, then the function does not make much sense inside the `Player` class. Depending on your final use case, you can access the attribute directly:

```py
print(player.primary_color)
>>>'blue'
print(player.secondary_color)
>>>'pink'
```